# How to fix product import Add/Update loading issue?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, upload, product-edit-page

On my product import page, I am unable to edit or upload new products as the circle never disappears.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: On the admin page? Is there any Browser error?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh yes on the admin page. Issue faced on all browsers

Comment: Could you check the Browser console?

Comment: can you please add product csv  format which you are using

Comment: Suggestion: try importing less number of products first. Like, try to import only 5 products and check if gets imported properly or not.
If it gets imported, then something is going wrong on your server while importing larger files. You can split the importing sheet into multiple parts and then import it.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra will check this way

Comment: @KazimNoorani will check on importing. The issue is I am unable to edit and upload new products using the admin backend

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh will check and get back to you. Could this issue happen because of wrong file/folder permissions?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh This is the error that I am getting 

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wQ-PjUwG2gSUxbNIPNmk3YHvvybB_Mlg

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh looking forward for your support

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? Please check and verify

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Wasif,
This is the screenshot of the error I am getting:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wQ-PjUwG2gSUxbNIPNmk3YHvvybB_Mlg

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157851)

Answer (score 1):

You should split the importing sheet into multiple parts and then import it. I got same issue when try to import large data.